# Xpath: How to combine these two child node to get parent node?

Tags: javascript, xml, selenium, xpath, puppeteer

I am new to XPath and confused. Anyone can have a quick glance and see what is wrong in my syntax?

I'm trying to select all direct child `div's` of `id="list-overview"` which has two child nodes somewhere down their tree containing `data-price<=20` and `a div containing "Orange" text`

```
let xy = $x(`//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./div/a/div/div/div[@data-price<=20]][./div/a/div/div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')]])`)
```

to break it up. I have tested these two separately and they worked.

```
`//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./div/a/div/div/div[@data-price<=20]]`
```

```
`//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./div/a/div/div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')])]`
```

I just can't seem to combine them somehow and not sure what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Tried the suggestions and the following xpath doesn't throw an exception anymore. But it returns empty Array while there are elements matching price < 20 and fruit="Orange"

```
$x(`//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./div/a/div/div/div[@data-price<=20] and ./div/div/a/div/div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')]]`)
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @DebanjanB added pastebin: https://pastebin.com/r05zN8BR with comments on top of file.

Comment: I would recommend to update the main question with text based HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your idea, you are missing the logical `and` between these 2 conditions. I corrected the XPath expression accordingly. Please try this:

```js
let xy = $x(`//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./div/a/div/div/div[@data-price<=20] and ./div/a/div/div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')]])`)
```

**UPD**
Please try this:

```js
let xy = $x(`//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[.//div[@data-price<=20] and .//div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')]])`)
```

Comment: DOMException: Failed to execute '$x' on 'CommandLineAPI': The string is not a valid XPath expression. Does this mean the xpath is not found or the syntax is incorrect?

Comment: `$x(`//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./div/a/div/div/div[@data-price<=20] and ./div/div/a/div/div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')]]`)` Yay! No dom exception anymore. But it returns an emtpy array while there are elements that match the price < 20 and fruit = Orange.

Comment: 1) Great, but it seems that your expression here is exactly what I have suggested. No?
2) Please see my updated suggestion

Comment: @ prophet yes, your expression was correct. I must have left a parentheses somewhere.

Comment: I see internet connection problems. Looks like it is with stackoverflow servers. Anyway, please check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
$x(//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./div/a/div/div/div[@data-price<=20]][./div/a/div/div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')]]))
```

You could do this to combine both of them,

to tightly couple both the child

```
$x(//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./descendant::div[@data-price<=20]] and [./div/a/div/div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')]])
```

or to either have one of them and still you would want to proceed further.

```
$x(//*[@id="list-overview"]/div[./descendant::div[@data-price<=20]] or [./div/a/div/div[@class='fruit'][contains(.,'Orange')]])
```

Also, I have included `descendant` to make it more readable.

Comment: I am getting dom exception not valid xpath on both of your examples. I re-tested the xpath broken up in two seperately to double check and they are valid. Maybe the xpath is too long?

Comment: There was one extra parenthesis added, I have removed and updated my answer, Please try again.

Comment: unfortunately still giving dom exception

Comment: Is it possible to share HTML code ?

Comment: Yes, I made a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/r05zN8BR and mapped example values to real ones.